# Дополнительные параметры формы в POST методе при загрузке файла

Tags: html, post, java-ee, jsp

На jsp страничке надо отправить сервлету дополнительно строковое значение при нажатии кнопки (кнопка, которая загружает файл).

```
"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload File\"></input>"
```

Как это сделать в POST-методе?

```
if(c.getDocument() == null) {
    out.println("Загрузка документа:<br><br>" +
    "Выбрать файл для загрузки: <br />" +
    "<form action=\"/upload\" method=\"post\"" +
    "enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">" +
    "<input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" size=\"50\"/>" +
    "<br />" +
    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload File\"></input>"+
    "</form>");
    } else {
        out.println(c.getDocument());
    }
```

Comment: Я не шарю в Java, но чтобы передать значение кнопки на сервер, нужно для него определить атрибут `name` с нужным вам значением, то есть как и для любого другого элемента формы ...

Comment: Пробовал - не то...